# Question about style inside form elements

Tags: css

I don't understand why selecting form will apply the active class to the label:

```css
form :active {
  color: red;
}


form button {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
    <form>
      <label for="my-button">My button: </label>
      <button id="my-button" type="button">Try Clicking Me or My Label!</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: The same exact question had been asked from another user about 60 min before.

Comment: @Llazar probably a homework question ;)

Comment: note the *space* inside your selector .. :active is applying to the child element and not the form element

Comment: Yeah....If I do "form:active" it only applies to the label...Why?

Comment: in this case you will have inheritance and only label will inherit the value because button has already a default value specified

Answer (score 0):

"The :active selector is used to select and style the active link.
A link becomes active when you click on it."

With this:

```
form:active {
  color: red;
}
```

you set the color of form and all the elements inside to red when active (when you click anywhere on your form)

Comment: Thank you. So if I assign a CSS selector to the parent, it will always, unless otherwise stated, affect the children?

Comment: note the *space* in the selector of his code which is important